# Export to Excel doesn't work in edge browser

Tags: javascript, html

This is the javascript function

```
function fnExcelReport()
    {
          var tab_text="<table border='2px'><tr bgcolor='#87AFC6'>";
          var textRange; var j=0;
          tab = document.getElementById('tableID'); // id of table


          for(j = 0 ; j < tab.rows.length ; j++) 
          {     
                tab_text=tab_text+tab.rows[j].innerHTML+"</tr>";
                //tab_text=tab_text+"</tr>";
          }

          tab_text=tab_text+"</table>";

               var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
              var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE "); 

                 if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))      // If Internet Explorer
                    {
                           txtArea1.document.open("txt/html","replace");
                           txtArea1.document.write(tab_text);
                           txtArea1.document.close();
                           txtArea1.focus(); 
                            sa=txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs",true,"filename.xls");
                          }  
                  else                 //other browser not tested on IE 11
                      sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));  


                      return (sa);
      }
```

and it will invoked on button click

```
<button id="btnExport" onclick="fnExcelReport();"> EXPORT </button>
```

This code works in Chrome, Firefox and IE. This is not working in Edge. Please help.

Answer (score 5):

You are not catching Edge in your if

Edge will not have MSIE in the window.navigator.userAgent;
it will have something like this

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; <64-bit tags>) AppleWebKit/<WebKit Rev> (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/<Chrome Rev> Safari/<WebKit Rev> Edge/<EdgeHTML Rev>.<Windows Build>
```

So instead of checking for MSIE, you should be checking for Edge

Refer to this MS link [User-agent string changes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh869301(v=vs.85).aspx)

Also take a look [here](https://codepen.io/gapcode/pen/vEJNZN)

Refer to this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/p8o42kdh/

Couple of points.
1) instead of indexOf I used match

```
ua.match(/Edge/)
```

2) To create file content I used blob

```
var blob = new Blob(["tab_text"], {type: 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel'});
window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, 'msSaveBlob_testFile.xls');
```

Comment: I tried and it works like a charm. Thank you Dmitry!

Comment: I tried the jsfiddle link in Edge and it is not exporting the contents of the table.

Comment: @Dmitry https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59177227/why-is-download-to-xls-feature-is-not-working-in-edge-browser-but-works-in-chro Can you please help with this question